# Snapping or Shrink wrapping only a part of an object to a specified place on another object

Tags: snapping, shrinkwrap

There are many videos of snapping whole objects to another. I can snap a cube to a cube. But it all seems to fall apart if I want to do something more complex like snapping only one face of an object, to just one face on the surface of another?

As an example: How would you snap one face on the surface on Suzanne's rounded nose, to the side of a cylinder surface and then be able to drag and rotate Suzanne while still staying snapped to the surface of the cylinder AND not distorting the head-object?

I have some complex shapes that only need parts of them snapped to other complex shapes' faces but try as I might the 2 objects are snapping in the wrong places or shrinking as flattened. As an example, a curved sticking-out air scoop on the curved surface of an engine cover, whose edges need to be snapped and conform to the sides of the round surface of an engine cover.  So I need only the edges of the scoop to snap/wrap onto the surface of the curved cover, but when trying to follow the shrink wrap online tutorials, my scoop is flattening itself to the engine surface! How do I specify which surfaces to snap or shrink to, while leaving the rest of the object intact? What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1AZybSzl8w&ab_channel=BlenderSecrets

Comment: Quick look, not tried yet, but very possible! 
I'll circle back if i stumble with something, but this looks like what I need.
Thanks!!

Comment: It's a good technique, and there are many other videos out there about it if you get stuck

Comment: I tried this, worked!! 
Thank you!!